# Speed difference between rear wheel and front wheel drive

Tags: drivetrain

Hypothetically if we have two almost identical cars with identical attributes (horse power, engine size, weight, etc.) , but one of them is front wheel drive and the other is rear wheel drive. My question is:

- Which car will accelerate, and ultimately go faster?

Comment: I think the RWD will have better mechanical grip due to weight distribution and shifting upon acceleration...we'll see what the community says.

Comment: Is horse power / torque measured at the crank or at the wheels?  FF and RR tend to have lower parasitic loses than FR vehicles.  If it is measured at the crank, the FF and RR vehicle would have an advantage.  Guess that would put us right back where we started though...

Comment: Please forgive an ignorant question, I know F = front and R = rear, but I'm not following what you mean by FF, RR, and FR. I have a feeling I'm going to feel really dumb when you tell me.. lol

Comment: FF usually means front engined front drive, and RR rear engined rear drive. So FR would be front engined rear wheel drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So two things to consider, acceleration from stopped, and top end speed. And based on your question, the following are identical:

- Engine horsepower
- Aerodynamics
- Gear ratios
- Tire size

And the only difference is one is a transverse mounted front wheel drive, and the other is a rear wheel drive.

**Acceleration from a stop**
In this case I think if the two cars have enough horsepower to break the tires loose so they are slipping rather than driving the car forward (doing a burnout), then the RWD would have some advantage. That's due to the weight transfer mentioned by @DucatiKiller in the above comment allowing more horsepower to be applied to the tires without breaking them loose.

**Top Speed**
For the top end, it's a question of force applied to drive the car forward vs drag. But, there is one more thing that's different between the two. The transverse mounted FWD has a much shorter drive train than the RWD. Same components ultimately (transmission and a differential) just no long drive shaft. Honestly, the amount of energy lost in heating up the longer drive train when compared to the FWD shorter path is negligible compared to the losses in aerodynamic drag. So if I had to bet, the FWD would technically be faster by an amount to small to be measured or matter.

Comment: If all things were equal, I'd agree with you on the acceleration part, but on top speed, if aero drag was the same between the two vehicles (ie: *all things being equal*), **neither would win the top speed war**. I'm very glad you pointed out this was actually two questions, not a single one.

Comment: I disagree on the acceleration part. The front wheel drive car would have more of the weight over top of the drive wheels, 70/30. The rear wheel drive car is split roughly 50/50. If the weight of the two cars was the same then the front wheel drive car would have more traction.

Comment: If I understand correctly when the car accelerates the weight of the car distributes itself to the back end of the car. Correct me if I'm wrong, but since the RWD car has more weight back than the FWD car, the RWD car has more contact (so to say) between the tires and the surface so it'll propel itself much easier just like @DucatiKiller said.

Comment: I think a lot of this depends on just how much horsepower the two cars have. If they are powerful engines and tires that grip well there will be a lot of acceleration and there will be a lot of weight transfer to the rear wheels. Maybe or maybe not enough to overcome the cars front to rear weight ratio. If the cars are like my 2000 Toyota Camry even with both chipmunks running as fast as they can there won't be much acceleration.. lol So, I think we would need to define things a little more because @vini_i has a really good point, in the FWD the weight is already on the wheels.

Comment: So, if @KarxMarl is ok with it, lets break down the acceleration from a stop into two more cases. Case 1: the FWD car has a 70/30 front to rear weight ratio, and the RWD is 55/45. The horsepower available to both is measured at the crank and is 120 BHP. In case 2, same front to rear weight ratios, but the engines produce 350 BHP. In both cases the cars weigh a total of lets say 3500 lbs.  This is a great thought question, love this!

Comment: So if I've understood so far, in case 1 the FWD car will accelerate faster cause of better weight distribution on the tires and since there no weight transfer to the back due to low engine power. And in case 2 the RWD would be faster cause of a lot more power and torque shifting the cars balance backwards?

Comment: I wouldn't say there is zero weight transfer in case one, but there will be so little that having the engine over the drive wheels swamps that effect. So yes, in case 1 the FWD would have the advantage. In case 1 the RWD doesn't have nearly enough weight transfer to make up for that hunk of steel over the front wheels... And the differential isn't enough weight to make up for it..

Comment: I meant negligible weight transfer, don't know why I put 'no'.

Comment: It's all good. :-)

Comment: You all are forgetting one important detail of the question: ***all things being equal*** ... the OP pointed this out by saying *identical cars/identical attributes* ... you are adjusting the parameters and therefor invalidating your argument ... just a thought.

Comment: But we didn't change that they are equal, just the level at which they are equal.

Comment: If your measuring power at the crank and comparing a front engine front wheel drive to a front engine rear wheel drive (as it seems to be from the weight distribution). The FWD will have an advantage due to less parasitic losses.  In case 1, this would give the FWD a definite win.  In case 2, it would be close.  RWD could out launch, but FWD might be able to catch up afterwards.

Comment: I've been wondering about that parasitic loss. Is it really that much higher in a RWD car? Both systems have a transmission and a differential,  is the extra loss from twisting in the drive shaft,  universal joints,  etc?

Comment: Ive done a bit of drag racing so I am thinking of this in terms of 60ft (launch) and 1/4 mile (acceleration) time.  If you want equal power, look at 2 cars with the same mph in the quarter.

Comment: I've heard FF manual is 10, FF auto is 15, FR manual is 15, FR auto is 20.

Comment: @rpmerf Do you know what the units of those numbers is?

Comment: Percent power loss between crank and wheels.

Comment: Ok so considering only manual transmissions it's still an extra 10% to be RWD. Not huge but nothing to dismiss either.  Very cool.  I wonder if that data is published for individual car models somewhere.  Hmmmmm